# Error when executing service method 'getStats'

Tags: c#, grpc

Im trying to do a client-server streaming and when I try to stream from the client to the server this error logs in server console: Error when executing service method 'getStats'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Object' while attempting to activate 't_stat_grpc.Services.HotelStatService'.

***getStats method***

```
public class HotelStatService : hotelStat.hotelStatBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<HotelStatService> _logger;
    public HotelStatService(ILogger<HotelStatService> logger, object httpClientFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public override async Task<dataToServer> getStats(IAsyncStreamReader<dataToServer> requestStream, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        var response = null as dataToServer;

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<dataToServer, dataToServer>();
        });

        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        await foreach(var request in requestStream.ReadAllAsync())
        {
            response = mapper.Map<dataToServer>(request);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

**This is where I call it**

```
while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Clique enter para enviar os dados para o servidor");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Conectando ao servidor...");
            var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5002");
            var client = new hotelStat.hotelStatClient(channel);
            var stream = client.getStats();
            Console.WriteLine("Conectado");
            Console.WriteLine("A enviar dados para o servidor...");
            string connectionString = $"Data Source=(localhost);Initial Catalog=hotel;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();

            var listaStats = connection.Query<dataToServer>("SELECT top(5) * FROM t_stat").ToList();
            
            foreach (var item in listaStats)
            {
                try
                {
                    var data = mapper.Map<dataToServer>(item);
                    await stream.RequestStream.WriteAsync(data);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Dados enviados com sucesso!");
            Console.WriteLine("Disconectando...");
            connection.Close();
        }
```

(If you need to check any code, just ask I will be able to show you)

Comment: The exception mentions this is about `HotelStatService`. Can you post the constructor of it? It apparently contains a parameter that shouldn't be there as the DI fails on it.

Comment: I edited with all the `HotelStatService` code @Ray

Comment: It's trying to DI an object for your `httpClientFactory`. You'll want to register the service as IHttpClientFactory, not object. More: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Im a kinda confused, @MatthewM. (Sorry to bother you, im new to GRPC)

Comment: This is about .NET's IoC / DI technique, not gRPC itself. Your `object` parameter makes no sense to it and you should give it a resolvable type like Matthew said, apparently `IHttpClientFactory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Program.cs`, add:

```cs
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
```

In your `HotelStatService` class, change the constructor to:

```cs
private readonly ILogger<HotelStatService> _logger;
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

public HotelStatService(ILogger<HotelStatService> logger, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
}
```

Alternatively, just **remove** the IHttpClientFactory parameter altogether if you're not using it.